# Couldn't determine Dialect for "oracle"

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, oracle19c

I am using Spring boot(2.3.5), Oracle19c DB, and Hibernate(5.4).

I tried to make multi-datasource connection, but I keep getting a dialect error `Couldn't determine Dialect for "oracle"`.

> Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@2ba9ed19. Please provide a Dialect.

I basically followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@mmafrar/configuring-multiple-data-sources-with-spring-boot-2-and-spring-data-jpa-8e236844e80f) to configure multiple data sources.

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource-primary.username=oracleprimary
spring.datasource-primary.password=oracleprimary
spring.datasource-primary.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl

spring.datasource-secondary.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource-secondary.username=oraclesecondary
spring.datasource-secondary.password=oraclesecondary
spring.datasource-secondary.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl
```

Primary configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.foo.primary.repository"})
public class PrimaryDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-primary")
    public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-primary.configuration")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource(@Qualifier("primaryDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties) {
        return primaryDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder primaryEntityManagerFactoryBuilder, @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource primaryDataSource) {

        Map<String, String> primaryJpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        primaryJpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");

        return primaryEntityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(primaryDataSource)
                .packages("com.foo.primary.model")
                .persistenceUnit("primaryDataSource")
                .properties(primaryJpaProperties)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory primaryEntityManagerFactory) {

        return new JpaTransactionManager(primaryEntityManagerFactory);
    }
```

Second configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.foo.secondary.repository"})
public class SecondaryDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-secondary")
    public DataSourceProperties secondaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-secondary.configuration")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource(@Qualifier("secondaryDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties secondaryDataSourceProperties) {
        return secondaryDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder secondaryEntityManagerFactoryBuilder, @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource secondaryDataSource) {

        Map<String, String> secondaryJpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        secondaryJpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");

        return secondaryEntityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(secondaryDataSource)
                .packages("com.foo.secondary.model")
                .persistenceUnit("secondaryDataSource")
                .properties(secondaryJpaProperties)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("secondaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory secondaryEntityManagerFactory) {

        return new JpaTransactionManager(secondaryEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

I also tried `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`, and set `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` in `application.properties`, but nothing changed.

How can I properly configure dialect for oracle?

Comment: Try to set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`

Comment: @SternK, I set it in `application.properties`, and no success.

Comment: **Note:** this problem only affects Spring Boot versions `2.3.x`. `2.2.x` worked seamlessly because there was no strict `Dialect` facility yet. `2.4.x` once again works OOTB, because [official support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/478) for the `OracleDialect` was added in Spring Data JDBC 2.1, which in turn, is referenced by Boot versions ≥`2.4.0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC [does not support oracle dialect](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/20/migrating-to-spring-data-jdbc-2-0). You need to define your dialect that implements `JdbcDialectProvider`.

```
public final class OracleDialect implements DialectResolver.JdbcDialectProvider {

    private static Dialect getDialect(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
        String name = metaData.getDatabaseProductName().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);

        if (name.contains("oracle")) {
            return AnsiDialect.INSTANCE;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Dialect> getDialect(JdbcOperations operations) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(operations.execute((ConnectionCallback<Dialect>) OracleDialect::getDialect));
    }
}
```

Add `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` dependency in your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml`.

Then, [as mentioned in the blog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/20/migrating-to-spring-data-jdbc-2-0), create `spring.factories` file in `resources/META-INF`, and paste the following command:

`org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$JdbcDialectProvider=<your-package>.OracleDialect`

Also, since both databases you use are the same (OracleDB), you do not need to set `.properties()` for entity manager. As @SternK mentioned, you can have `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` in your `application.properties` only.

Comment: Thanks a lot and thanks for providing reference from Spring blog